# ARKit 2 freezes: a bug or my misfortune?

Tags: ios, arkit, beta

Is it just me who experiences the whole scene freezing in ARKit on iOS 12? It usually happens when you use the app for too long in a space that generates too dense point cloud. After certain amount of time, the whole picture starts to lag and then would stop moving at all, until you cover the camera, or turn it away from your objects, or reset AR session.

Since I have updated to iOS 12, I started to experience this issue, but I searched a few forums to see if someone else got this problem and couldn’t find anyone. I wonder if it’s just me, or is it a common bug?

UPD: iOS 12 beta 2 - the issue still persists

Comment: Does the issue reproduce when using one of the ARKit Xcode template projects or Apple's sample code? Have you profiled your app using Instruments? Even if you're not sure if it's your bug or Apple's (especially when beta OS/SDK is involved), it's a good idea to [file bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Both. Even with AR preview in Safari

Comment: Is this issue still there? I am still facing this issue on setting OverlaySkScene to my ARSCNView

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having the problem? I faced a much worse problem today after upgrading to Xcode10 and iOS 12. I was so crushed when all my ARKit 1.5 projects faced freezing after the first frame was captured from the start.

I managed to solve it by changing project setting, the Deployment Target under General to 12.0. I restarted Xcode just to be sure. All my ARKit projects work now.

I hope this helps, if I find more issues with image recognition freezing on iOS 12 I will mark them here.

Comment: I tried changing the deployment target to iOS 12.0 but no luck :( App still freezes. BTW app freezes when i set OverlaySKScene to my ARSceneView.

Comment: @yaali I have finished the app by the end of June, so can't really tell if the issue is gone now or not. I have had same problem with their Measure app in beta 2, but now I tend to think that the issue is not present. However, I should say that I've never seen anything related to ARKit freezes in their changelog.

Comment: In order to sort out the problem back then, I had to implement a reset button, which would wipe out the ARSession completely. And yeah, I was using iOS 12.0 by default. I should also say that I haven't updated XCode since beta 1, so if I were to make another attempt, I would update everything to the latest version. Although, I won't be surprised if the freezing ARKit will make its way into release version.