# ARKit Image detection Freezing camera

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I had image detection working properly in ARKit 1.5, but in ARKit 2.0 whenever I launch my application it freezes after what looks like 1 frame of the camera. I can still interact with an object that automatically spawns on the screen, but the camera stops updating. I am using the Unity plugin and every time I change the fields under Image Tracking in the Unity AR Camera Manager script I seem to have this problem. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891444/arkit-2-freezes-a-bug-or-my-misfortune Thank you. Seems more like a bug now.

Comment: Yeah it only seems to happen to me when I try adding image detection, but it happens consistently.

Comment: It happens to me even without any detections. iOS 12 beta 2 made it slightly better, but still freezes sometimes

Comment: Somewhat solved. Make sure you update the target SDK on both Unity and XCode to 12 when building. Mine was still 11.3 by default I believe. Simple mistake I didn't notice.

Comment: I use 12.0 by default. Let me know if the issue persists

Answer (score 2):

This bug is occurred on below environment, I found out.

- on Xcode 10.0
- DeploymentTarget: iOS11.0~11.4
- build on the device which is iOS12

I've debugged a lot of pattern of environments.

Finally, I tried on **Xcode 10.1** and then found out this bug has been fixed, I thought... **But this solution is not perfect. I couldn't solve the problem on iPhone XS Max.**

Finally and Finally, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101805/10339551) is the best.

Thanks.

Comment: [Added] This solution may be also useful but https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101805/10339551 is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a workaround from the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/104361).

**Use JPEG format instead of PNG for ARReferenceImage.**

That's it. I tried this and fixed it even on XS Max (iOS12.0.1).