# ARKit 2.0 screen is unresponsive on using "OverlaySKScene"

Tags: swift4, arkit, skscene, xcode10, ios12

I have a couple of projects developed using **ARKit 1.5** and it was working fine till **iOS 11.4.1**. When I upgraded my iOS to **Version 12 beta** and ran it using **Xcode 10 beta** (the latest version till date), my AR session became very unresponsive and freezes.

This freezing is even bad for projects where I have used `OverlaySKScene` for my `ARSceneView`. Is this a bug that I should file or only occurs to me and I should do some code optimization? If so, please help me with ideas on how to optimize the performance.

I read this thread [ARKit 2 freezes: a bug or my misfortune?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891444/arkit-2-freezes-a-bug-or-my-misfortune) and changed my deployment target to iOS 12 but still no luck :(

**Note:** It is very difficult for me to completely redo the app using ARKit 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It is because I was doing a lot of extensive coding inside below renderer method. I was updating my `SpriteKit` components of my SKScene in the below method.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) { 
    // some stuff
}
```

Now replaced the code in below,

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) { 
    // some stuff
}
```

Now the application stopped freezing. But still I can see some lag.

Comment: @ yaali i have tried your code but still if i place virtual objects in surface that time ARKit camera was freezing. and i am getting following log. [Technique] World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints [1].
please guide me. thanks